# Using MAAS to deploy ubuntu 14.04 on HP DL380 gen9

Tags: server, uefi, hp, maas

I'm new to MAAS and I'm having trouble installing ubuntu 14.04 on HP DL380 gen9 server,
I'm using latest MAAS version(1.9) and so far I was able to enlist the node after the curtin installation on MAAS but after the installation is done the server shut-down, once I turn the server back on and reinstall and acting the same(shut-down)
So far I tried installing it with the Legacy-BIOS (booting pxelinux.0 file)
and now I'm trying with UEFI, for some reason when I was trying to boot with filename "bootx64.efi" it didn't booted, but when I changed to "grubx64.efi" It did boot and started with the installation.

Can anyone tell me if I need to set any special setting for deploying this server(HP Proliant DL380 gen9).

Another thing is, How can I know what are the user-name and password I need to use in order to log to the machine once installed.
Can I edit the curtin installer with my own user/password?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing some steps. To install a server via MAAS, there are (broadly speaking) three steps:

1. **Enlist** -- You manually power on the sever (via a button press, `ipmitool` command, or whatnot). It starts up, PXE-boots from the MAAS server, and is registered with the MAAS server so that it shows up in the menu. At this point, the MAAS server has only very basic information on the node, such as its MAC address and IPMI credentials.
2. **Commission** -- To commission, you select the "Commission" option from the node's Web UI page. (It's a sub-menu, and I don't recall the menu name, offhand.) During commissioning, the MAAS server tells the node to start up (via IPMI, typically), the node PXE-boots, and MAAS collects more detailed information on the node, such as its available RAM and disk space. When commissioning is done, the node shuts down again.
3. **Deploy** -- To deploy, you select the "Deploy" option from the same submenu where "Commission" had been. You may also have a chance to choose which Ubuntu version (or custom OS) to deploy, depending on how you've set up the MAAS server. Again, MAAS tells the node to start up, it PXE-boots, and MAAS install Ubuntu on the node. After deployment is finished, the system should stay up and you should be able to log in via SSH from the MAAS server.

From your description, I suspect that you enlisted the node, but have neither commissioned nor deployed it. Neither enlistment nor commissioning permanently installs Ubuntu on the server; that happens only during deployment. You must do those two additional steps before you can begin using the node. Once this is done, you should be able to log in from the MAAS server via SSH, or conceivably from other systems, if you've added SSH public keys to the MAAS server. Nodes deployed via a "stock" MAAS *do not* support console logins. If you need that feature, you'll need to either adjust your MAAS preseeds or set it up manually after deploying, by changing the password on the `ubuntu` account or by creating a new account.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response,

As for now I managed to enlist my server in MAAS(using MAAS 1.7),
But whenever I hit commission, it fails with "Failed to power on node — Timeout after 7 tries"

The power type for the enlisted node is: IPMI
and power driver is LAN_2_0
I gave the right credentials, and I even saw that MAAS created power user in the enlisted machine, what could be the issue?

Comment: You say you "gave the right credentials," but MAAS should create its own IPMI account (username "maas" and a random password). You *can* change this if you need to, but you should ordinarily leave it alone. You can test your ability to control the node using `ipmitool`. If that works and MAAS doesn't, then I recommend you start poking around in the MAAS logs to try to find the cause.

Comment: Hey, I finally managed to install 2 Nodes with MAAS(thanks to Rod Smith), now I want to delete a node from MAAS? what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: From the node's page in the MAAS web UI: Take action -> Delete.